# Computername write to txt file (%computername%)

Tags: vbscript

If a computer run's the script on Wednesday, i want that it creates a %computername*.txt file in a netwok map. In batch script i can to it with %computername%.txt, what code can i use it for VBS script?

---

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If DatePart("W",Date) = 4 Then
    'Today is Wednesday, so run the virus scan
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("\\server\Avast Scan Log\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt")
    WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\Alwil Software\Avast4\aswcmd"" M: /m /*", , True
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>> WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%")
>>
WINXPSP3
>> WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Network").Computername
>>
WINXPSP3
```

Comment: Hi, Tnx for your reply. It doesn't work. It is just showing the Computername in Window. I just want it to create %computername%.txt file on network location. We have 50 computers here. Every computers must write their own computername to their own txt file. Like com1.txt, com2.txt, com3.txt etc.

Comment: Come on, what about incorporating the returned computername into your script by loading it into a variable and using that variable in the filename you create with `objFSO.CreateTextFile`? We are here to help you, not to spell out every line of code until it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WshNetwork object to get the computer name as suggested.  It looks like this.

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strComputer = WshNetwork.ComputerName

If DatePart("W",Date) = 4 Then
    'Today is Wednesday, so run the virus scan
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("\\server\Avast Scan Log\" & strComputer & ".txt")
    WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\Alwil Software\Avast4\aswcmd"" M: /m /*", , True
End If
```